# What happened to Naruto's grandparents?

Tags: naruto

Was Kushina the last of the Uzumaki clan and if not why did none of her family take Naruto on as an orphan? Who was the Namikaze's and why have we never heard of another one?

Were both Kushina and Minato orphans themselves? What is the story behind Naruto's extended family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Uzumaki clan and it's village was destroyed some time after Kushina came to Konoha. Survivors went into hiding and and spread throughout the world.
It is unlikely that direct relatives of Kushina survived.
Regarding Minatos parents we just don't know anything about them.
But considering that the third shinobi world war took place at that time where even children barely out of the academy were send to fight it might be a reasonable assumption that his parents died in it.

Sources:
[Minato](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Minato_Namikaze)
[Kushina](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kushina_Uzumaki)
[Uzumaki clan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uzumaki_clan)
[3rd Shinobi World War](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Third_Shinobi_World_War)

Comment: Do you think that Karin is related to Kushina?

Comment: @NeilMeyer both are from the Uzumaki clan. How close they are related is unknown.

Comment: Kishi really needs to make that Minato series.

Comment: @NeilMeyer if he does, I'm pretty sure it won't reveal as much.

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru CHECK ou the result of that spinoff poll.

Answer (score -4):

put right before Kushina got kidnapped she went inside the apartment and asked if anyone was home like she had parents and we all know that orphans in Naruto don't get adopted

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. Please provide any manga chapter or episode number to support your answer